# Sharepoint calendar list view webpart connected with filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-server, office

I have a requirement in office online 365 in which following things are needed.

Calendar list with custom field "Events", type is choice (General,Marriage,Birthday)
Need to create a dropdown in which above field's value should bind.
When user select "General" then only General events should display, birthday and marriage should not display.
Main thing, View should be only calendar View and I have tried sharepoint list filter and list view webpart but calendar view is not supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar View not support OOTB filters connection. it is disabled for calendar view,
you need to change view(not calendar view) so OOTB filters works and get connected to your view

plz refer [this](http://www.aasoftech.com/products/lists/how%20to%20filter%20sharepoint%20calendar%20dynamically/allitems.aspx) link

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks, this i reviewed yesterday. But this is not a sandbox solution. Also i am practicing on office online 365 so needed sandbox solution. Also some code side will also helpful